# Parameters not getting passed in REST call. But works fine in postman

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, controller, endpoint

I'm performing Integration testing in below getPlanPreferenceRules endpoint and the parameters values are not passed over to preferences-admin-service. However, when i try to test the same in postman it works fine.

Below is the code that performs REST call.

```
@Override
    public ServiceClientResponse<GetPlanPrefRulesResponse> getPlanPrefereneRules(GetPlanPrefRulesRequest parameters,
            String currentUserId, String correlationId, String requestorApp) {

        RequestEntity<?> targetRequest = 
                createGetPlanPrefRulesRequest(parameters, currentUserId, correlationId, requestorApp);

        return this.restClientService.exchangeAndParse(
                this.getRulesRestTemplate, targetRequest, new TypeReference<GetPlanPrefRulesResponse>(){});
    }
```

Below is the Spring controller service:

```
@GetMapping(value = PATH_PLAN_PREF_RULES)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPlanPrefRules(
            @Valid  final GetPlanPrefRulesRequest request )
    {
        log.info("getPlanPrefRulesDataRequest: Entering: GetPlanPrefRulesRequest={}", request); 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.getPlanPreferenceRulesService.getPlanPrefRules(request));
    }
```

Below is the code that creates the request for the REST call:

```
protected RequestEntity<?> createGetPlanPrefRulesRequest(
            final GetPlanPrefRulesRequest parameters,
            final String currentUserId,
            final String correlationId,
            final String requestorApp)
    {
        URI targetUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(this.preferencesServiceUri)
                .path(this.rulesPath).build().toUri();

        HttpHeaders targetHeaders = createHeaders(
                currentUserId,
                correlationId,
                requestorApp);

        return new RequestEntity<>(
                parameters,
                targetHeaders,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                targetUri);
    }
```

I am not sure what i am missing. Any inputs appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Update this method

```
@GetMapping(value = PATH_PLAN_PREF_RULES)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPlanPrefRules(
            @RequestBody @Valid  final GetPlanPrefRulesRequest request )
    {
        log.info("getPlanPrefRulesDataRequest: Entering: GetPlanPrefRulesRequest={}", request); 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.getPlanPreferenceRulesService.getPlanPrefRules(request));
    }
```